# while using python pd.DatetimeIndex how can I extract two instances?

Tags: python, pandas

```
dt = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['datetime'])


df['date'] = dt.date
df['day'] = dt.day
df['month'] = dt.month
df['year'] = dt.year
df['hour'] = dt.hour
df['dow'] = dt.dayofweek
df['woy'] = dt.weekofyear
df['weeks_start'] = (dt - min(dt)).days / 7
```

Here I'm studying bicycle borrowing demand in Kaggle. With others' solution, I want to test with another column, which is year and month.

In turn what I want to create is `df['year_month']` which shows concatenated version of year and month for example 2011_1.

But just doing `str(df['year']) + str(df['month'])` does not qualify such job since it is typed as pandas array.

How can I successfully concatenate these two as a new column and do the one hot encoding for this?

Comment: Would `dt.strftime('%Y_%m')` or `pd.Index(dt.strftime('%Y_%m'))` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, let's try:

```
dt.year.astype(str) + '_' + dt.month.astype(str)
```

Since, dt is aleady a datetimeindex object, you can access the year and month directly using `.year` and `.month` then cast them as strings using `astype` and add them together.  Output:

```
Index(['2017_1', '2017_2', '2017_3', '2017_4', '2017_5', '2017_6', '2017_7',
       '2017_8', '2017_9', '2017_10', '2017_11', '2017_12', '2018_1', '2018_2',
       '2018_3', '2018_4', '2018_5', '2018_6', '2018_7', '2018_8', '2018_9',
       '2018_10', '2018_11', '2018_12', '2019_1', '2019_2', '2019_3', '2019_4',
       '2019_5', '2019_6', '2019_7', '2019_8', '2019_9', '2019_10', '2019_11',
       '2019_12', '2020_1', '2020_2', '2020_3', '2020_4', '2020_5', '2020_6',
       '2020_7', '2020_8', '2020_9', '2020_10', '2020_11', '2020_12', '2021_1',
       '2021_2', '2021_3', '2021_4', '2021_5', '2021_6', '2021_7', '2021_8',
       '2021_9', '2021_10', '2021_11', '2021_12'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: this didn't worked at all  
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U11') dtype('<U11') dtype('<U11')

Comment: @jh.shin Okay,you can try df['year'].astype(str) + '_' + df['month'].astype(str)